# Run default Lead Assignment in trigger

Tags: trigger, custom-field, assignment-rules

I want run a rule from trigger (Lead Assignment rule - default) when a new lead is created. I tried something but its not working. Don't know which one is correct way to do that. below you can find my code with bugs. I got something from this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/lead-assignment-rule-in-a-trigger) but I don't want to do database operations. I just want to run my rule. Someone please help me.

```
trigger leadAssignment on Lead (after insert) {
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if(l.My_Field__c != null && !l.My_Field__c.isEmpty())
        {
           Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
           dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;   
        }
    }
}
```

`isEmpty()` not working any better way to do that?
If this information is not enough just comment it I will update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...but I don't want to do database operations".  Why???

Comment: Did you read [@crop1645 answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13771/2212) to the post you referred to? You must call an @future method for the lead reassignment via a DML operation. Also, if you're inserting new records, you can specify the lead assignment rule in dataloader. Also, the code you're using includes DML. Any change to the database is a DML operation.